# Datatable Tool options - Excel,CSV,PDF and Copy is not working

Tags: datatables

I downloaded dataTables.tableTools.js and trying to run it, but Excel,CSV,PDF and Copy is not working only print option is working,I followed all steps given in document.

I could see the mouse pointer changing on hover.

```js
$("#_dynamicReportContainer").empty();
var tableDefinition = "<table id='_dynamicReportTable'><thead><tr>";

// do some updates here...

tableDefinition = tableDefinition.concat('</tr></thead></table>');
$('#_dynamicReportContainer').append(tableDefinition);
var table = $('#_dynamicReportContainer').children();

// do some updates here...

reportData.each(function (k, v) {
       table.append("<tr><td>" + startDate + "</td><td>" + queryStringSecondary + "</td><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v + "</td></tr>");
});

// do some updates here...

$('#_dynamicReportTable').dataTable({ "autoWidth": false, "bInfo": false, paging: false,
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "aButtons": ["print", "csv"],
        "sSwfPath": window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/_layouts/TimeSheet/js/ui/supportFiles/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
    }
});
```

I could see the data on the table(datatable) and could print however other options(Excel,CSV...) are not working.

Comment: make sSwfPath to an absolute path.

Comment: Below is also not working: $('#_dynamicReportTable').dataTable({ "autoWidth": false, "bInfo": false, paging: false, "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip', "tableTools": { "aButtons": ["print", "csv"], "sSwfPath": window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/_layouts/TimeSheet/js/ui/supportFiles/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf" } });

Comment: and if you take the resulting path, and try to load it in a browser, does it load the .swf? Why do you construct an absolute path anyway, instead of using the path you positively know directs to the .swf?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: delete the "sSwfPath" from the initialization and add the following code:

```
TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = "your path";
// mine was TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = "<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/sw//copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";
```